# Is there not an idiomatic way to have a (secondary) constructor that derives values for the primary constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a  simple Kotlin class:

```
data class ValveSpan(val begin:Duration, val end:Duration, val key:String):Comparable<ValveSpan> {
    ...
}
```

Because it's a data class, I *must* have a primary constructor with one or more values in it. And that's fine, I like the terse expression of it.

But when I want to make a secondary constructor that populates one from doc like object (similar to JSON), it gets weird:

```
constructor(doc:TSON):this(doc["begin"].duration!!, doc["end"].duration!!, doc["valves"].sequence!!.first()!!.string!!) {
    // do nothing here, because, uh, I had to do it all in the delegated primary????
}
```

Basically, the intent of the secondary constructor, is to take the input, compute some values for the primary constructor, and then call the primary with those values. But it seems I have to do them inline in the primary constructor. Which as the derivation gets more and more complex gets more and more complicated. I'd really like to have written something like:

```
constructor(doc:TSON) {
    var sanitizedBegin =  doc["begin"].duration ?: 0.minutes
    var sanitizedEnd = doc["end"].duration ?: 0.minutes
    var sanitizedKey = doc["valves"].sequence?.firstOrNull()?.string ?: ""
    primaryConstructor(sanitizedBegin, sanitizedEnd, sanitizedKey)
}
```

Is there no way to delegate to the primary constructor, without having to do all of the bridging computation inline?

Comment: Nope. Java doesn't support that either actually (at least last time I tried)

Comment: Way to give a guy hope. :/ I'm trying to be a better iOS/Android swift/kotlin polyglot. Kotlin is pretty cool. But there's times where I just want to smack my head til it's bloody on the keyboard.

Comment: using the companion object would suit this use case pretty well, it will act like the class's factory and you can have as much derivation logic as you want.

Comment: what would that look like @AhmedAshrafGamal?

Comment: I'd have to have static-esque factory method on companion, right? Basically `fun doc(doc:TSON) : ValveSpan { ... }` in lieu of the `constructor` keyword? And then instead of creating them via something that looked like a constructor (e.g. `ValveSpan(doc)`, I'd use `ValveSpan.doc(doc)` ?

Comment: Yup, will post the snippet in an answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484879/46375) of @ahmed-ashraf-gamal, you may also simulate calling a constructor from clients of ValveSpan by introducing a companion object that defines an invoke operator on the companion object.  For instance:

```
data class ValveSpan(val begin:Duration, val end:Duration, val key:String) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(doc:TSON): ValveSpan {
            var sanitizedBegin =  doc["begin"].duration ?: 0.minutes
            var sanitizedEnd = doc["end"].duration ?: 0.minutes
            var sanitizedKey = doc["valves"].sequence?.firstOrNull()?.string ?: ""
            return ValveSpan(sanitizedBegin, sanitizedEnd, sanitizedKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Which would then allow you call `ValveSpan(doc)`.

Comment: Didn't know that, nice :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the companion object for that purpose:

```
data class ValveSpan(val begin:Duration, val end:Duration, val key:String) {
    companion object {
        fun fromDoc(doc:TSON): ValveSpan {
            var sanitizedBegin =  doc["begin"].duration ?: 0.minutes
            var sanitizedEnd = doc["end"].duration ?: 0.minutes
            var sanitizedKey = doc["valves"].sequence?.firstOrNull()?.string ?: ""
            return ValveSpan(sanitizedBegin, sanitizedEnd, sanitizedKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ValveSpan.fromDoc(doc)
```